# SQL conditional relations

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have three tables:

```
Product(columns: Id, ProductType, ProductId, ...)

Apple(columns: Id, ProductType(will be always 1), ...)

Orange(columns: Id, ProductType(will be always 2), ...)
```

If `Product` a has `ProductType` 1, I want to relate it with `Apple` Table, If 2, then To `Orange` Table. Is it possible in SQL?

Comment: Which SQL? (SQL Server, MySQL etc..)

Comment: [This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/646d3/1) code should help to get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product p
JOIN Apple a ON (p.ProductType = 1 AND p.ProductId = a.Id)
JOIN Orange o ON (p.ProductType = 2 AND p.ProductId = o.Id)
```

Comment: I know how to write query in this case. I want to do this using foreign keys. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

you could do a union of all the subtypes then an outer join.